# How to "fix" broken Java Strings (charset-conversion)

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

I'm running a Servlet that takes POST requests from websites that aren't necessarily encoded in UTF-8. These requests get parsed with GSON and information (mainly strings) end up in objects.

Client side charset doesn't seem to be used for any of this, as Java just stores Strings in Unicode internally.

Now if a page sending a request has a non-unicode-charset, the information in the strings is garbled up and doesn't represent what was sent - it seems to be misinterpreted somewhere either in the process of being stringified by the servlet, or parsed by gson.

Assuming there is no easy way of fixing the root of the issue, is there a way of recovering that information, given the (misinterpreted) Java Strings and the charset identifier (i.e. "Shift_JIS", "Windows-1255") used to display it on the client's side?

Comment: Do you mean, "Assume that I can't fix the root cause" or "Is there a way to fix the root cause?"

Comment: ideally i'd love to fix the root cause, but i'd take means of recovering the data, too.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had need to do this before, but I believe that

```
final String realCharsetName = "Shift_JIS"; // for example
new String(brokenString.getBytes(), realCharsetName);
```

stands a good chance of doing the trick.

(This does however assume that encoding issues were entirely ignored while reading, and so the platform's default character set was used (a likely assumption since if people thought about charsets they probably would have got it right).  It also assumes you're decoding on a machine with the same default charset as the one that originally read the bytes and created the String.)

If you happen to know exactly which charset was incorrectly used to read the string, you can pass it into the `getBytes()` call to make this 100% reliable.

Comment: @BalusC it does not. i did try this in the beginning, but it just spits out a much longer string containing bogus characters. there seems to be some kind of byte-misinterpretation.

Comment: @jules: My comment must more be interpreted as: "This does **not** work because it's an URL-encoded value". See my answer for the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that it's obtained as a POST request parameter the following way

```
String string = request.getParameter("name");
```

then you need to URL-encode the string back to the original query string parameter value using the charset which the server itself was using to decode the parameter value

```
String original = URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");
```

and then URL-decode it using the intended charset

```
String fixed = URLDecoder.decode(original, "Shift_JIS");
```

As the better alternative, you could also just instruct the server to use the given charset directly *before* obtaining any request parameter by [`ServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29).

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("Shift_JIS");
String string = request.getParameter("name");
```

There's by the way no way to know about the charset which the client used to URL-encode the POST request body. Almost no of the clients specifies it in the `Content-Type` request header, otherwise the `ServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()` call would be already implicitly done by the servlet API based on that. You could determine it by checking `getCharacterEncoding()`, if it returns `null` then the client has specified none.

However, this does of course not work if the client has already properly encoded the value as UTF-8 or for any other charset. The `Shift_JIS` massage would break it again. There exist tools/API's to *guess* the original charset used based on the obtained byte sequence, but that's not 100% reliable. If your servlet concerns a public API, then you should **document** properly that it *only* accepts UTF-8 encoded parameters whenever the charset is not specified in the request header. You can then move the problem to the client side and point them on their mistake.

Comment: i should have been clearer: the data i'm getting strings out of is parsed from a POSTed JSON string. The request body is read into a string by a StringBuilder using a BufferedReader on the HttpServletRequest's getReader().

Comment: The same story still applies. You should URL-encode and URL-decode it back and forth. The reader *should* have used the proper encoding from the beginning on to read it. The `setCharacterEncoding()` does that. However, this is after all not going to work, see also my last paragraph. It's after all client's own mistake. You can impossibly support all thousand of different charsets as long as the client doesn't specify any charset in the request header.

Comment: thanks, so it IS a problem of the reader as i assumed. any chance of recovery, or is the process of reading it a lossy one?

Comment: As said, do a `request.setCharacterEncoding("Shift_JIS");` *before* you do `request.getReader()` if you are so certain that you will *always* retrieve `Shift_JIS` encoded requests. Recovering any existing data is easy with mentioned `URLEncoder` and `URLDecoder` classes.

Comment: charsets will vary, so a static solution is out of the question. the URLEncoder/URLDecoder variant does not work. here's what i got/get: http://pastebin.com/KqbU8gH9

Comment: Your `System.out.println()` target is using ISO-8859-1 to display the characters. Fix it to use UTF-8. If it's in for example Eclipse, do that by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding*. By the way, `å½¹å¡ä¸è¦§` is an ISO-8859-1 representation of `役員一覧` in UTF-8. So it was in UTF-8 **already**. I guess that this whole problem is just a misinterpretation caused by the fact that your `System.out.println()` target is not using the proper charset.

Comment: that change in eclipse doesn't change the console output. i also have a website outputting the string in proper utf-8 encoding and it's garbled up there just like in the console.

Comment: There's definitely somewhere incorrectly an ISO-8859-1 encoding going on. In my Eclipse environment, `System.out.println(new String("å½¹å¡ä¸è¦§".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));` results in `役員一覧` in the console.

Comment: that's weird - it doesn't for me.

Comment: Then your stdout encoding is still bogus.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to fix the problem is to ensure that when you read the content, you do so using the correct character encoding. Most frameworks and libraries will take care of this for you, but if you're manually writing servlets, it's something you need to be aware of. This isn't a shortcoming of Java. You just need to pay attention to the encodings. Specifically, the Content-Type header should contain useful information.

Any time you convert from a byte stream to a character stream in Java, you should supply a character encoding so that the bytes can be properly decoded into characters. See for example the [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that what you get is a string that was parsed as if it were UTF-8 but was encoded in Windows-1255? The solution would be to encode your string in UTF-8 and decode the result as Windows-1255.